# how to iterate scraping all the table in a list of url?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

So, I was trying to scrape a tale for a website, I manage to scrape the 1st URL's table, but I'm not sure how to iterate to the next URL.

Here's my for one URL :

```
u = 'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393739'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#openurl
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
web = driver.get(u)
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
iframe = soup.find('iframe')['src']
openiframe = driver.get(iframe)
iframehtml = driver.page_source
soupiframe = bs(iframehtml, 'html.parser')

#extracting table
df = pd.read_html(iframehtml)
table1 = df[1]
table2 = df[2]
table3 = df[3]

#cleanup table
t1 = table1.set_index([0, table1.groupby(0).cumcount()])[1].unstack(0)
t1['Remarks'] = table2.iloc[1]
t3 = table3.set_index([0, table3.groupby(0).cumcount()])[1].unstack(0)

#join all table
frame = [t1,t3]
merge = pd.concat(frame,axis=1,join="outer",ignore_index=False)
merge
```

and my output is :
[image]

and now, I don't know how to iterate for 2 or more URL in this script :

```
u = {'https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393739','https://www.bursamalaysia.com/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393738'}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#openurl
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
web = driver.get(u)
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
iframe = soup.find('iframe')['src']
openiframe = driver.get(iframe)
iframehtml = driver.page_source
soupiframe = bs(iframehtml, 'html.parser')

#extracting table
df = pd.read_html(iframehtml)
table1 = df[1]
table2 = df[2]
table3 = df[3]

#cleanup table
t1 = table1.set_index([0, table1.groupby(0).cumcount()])[1].unstack(0)
t1['Remarks'] = table2.iloc[1]
t3 = table3.set_index([0, table3.groupby(0).cumcount()])[1].unstack(0)

#join all table
frame = [t1,t3]
merge = pd.concat(frame,axis=1,join="outer",ignore_index=False)
merge
```

output should look like this :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import trio
import httpx
import pandas as pd

keys = [393738, 393739]


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}


allin = []


async def worker(channel):
    async with channel:
        async for key_ in channel:
            async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
                client.headers.update(headers)
                params = {
                    "e": key_
                }
                r = await client.get('https://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/viewHtml', params=params)
                all = pd.read_html(
                    r.text, index_col=0)
                df = all[1].T.join(all[-1].T)
                df['Remarks'] = all[2].iloc[1].name
                allin.append(df)


async def main():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nurse:

        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)

        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(3):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for k in keys:
                    await sender.send(k)

    finaldf = pd.concat(allin, ignore_index=True)
    print(finaldf)
    # finaldf.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
0 Date of change Type of change  ...     Reference No                                            Remarks
0     11/11/2011    Resignation  ...  CC-111111-50017  Resigned as Chief Executive Officer of the Com...  
1     31/12/2011         Others  ...  CC-110907-47379  It was Mr Yen Wen Hwa's desire to retire and t...  

[2 rows x 17 columns]
```

Comment: @Prophet what do you mean ?

Comment: @Prophet who in earth said for you that is `JS`?

Comment: What @Prophet ?? i think the whole code in python but still need command over that libraries

Comment: @BhavyaParikh No worries, i used to see such comments when people don't know what is an Async program is.

Comment: OK, sorry. I saw `async` several times here, not used to see that with Python selenium code.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη this library is new for never try it, I tried run it and i get error, not sure why i get the error while you get the output, here's the error - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you tried out the code as it is ? Or you’ve edited anything ? . Also try to print out the response and check if it’s 200 or something else !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη yes i copied the code as it is, you can see the error here : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YGv95rvJzZYzejc_KlOHzWElXvlgUriD?usp=sharing

Comment: Google Colab IP Address range is blocked by the receiver DNS. Try to run this code locally on your machine

Comment: @YazidYaakub [Google-Colab Response](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16tJnzjShaIA5B-xRjBAvPxx_wUlk4N5A?usp=sharing) with 503!

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη work like a charm! when run locally, ok got it