# How to shift a dataframe element-wise to fill NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fillna

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABCD'), 'b': ['E',np.nan,np.nan,'F']})
   a    b
0  A    E
1  B  NaN
2  C  NaN
3  D    F
```

I am trying to fill `NaN` with values of the previous column in the next row and dropping this second row. In other words, I want to combine the two rows with NaNs to form a single row without NaNs like this:

```
   a  b
0  A  E
1  B  C
2  D  F
```

I have tried various flavors of `df.fillna(method="<bfill/ffill>")` but this didn't give me the expected output.

I haven't found any other question about this problem, [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905295/how-to-replace-nans-by-preceding-or-next-values-in-pandas-dataframe) one. And actually that `DataFrame` is made from `list of DataFrame` by doing `.concat()`, you may notice that from indexes also. I am telling this because it may be easy to do in single row rather then in multiple rows.

I have found some suggestions to use `shift`, `combine_first` but non of them worked for me. You may try these too.

I also have found [this](https://kanoki.org/2019/08/17/pandas-coalesce-replace-value-from-another-column) too. It is a whole article about filling `nan` values but I haven't found problem/answer like mine.

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0).bfill()`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas no, It is filling that nan but not required row. It fills respectively lower two rows. But I want to fill it from next row first column.

Comment: try `df.groupby(level=0).ffill()`?

Comment: I don't know if that will work with dummy data or not but it is not working for real data(first data of question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK misunderstood what you wanted to do the first time. The dummy example was a bit ambiguous.

Here is another:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('ABCD'), 'b': ['E',np.nan,np.nan,'F']})
   a    b
0  A    E
1  B  NaN
2  C  NaN
3  D    F
```

To my knowledge, this operation does not exist with pandas, so we will use numpy to do the work.

First transform the dataframe to numpy array and [`flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) it to be one-dimensional. Then drop NaNs using [`pandas.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isna.html) that is working on a larger range types than [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html), and then [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the array to its original shape before transforming back to dataframe:

```
array = df.to_numpy().flatten()
pd.DataFrame(array[~pd.isna(array)].reshape(-1,df.shape[1]), columns=df.columns)
```

output:

```
   a  b
0  A  E
1  B  C
2  D  F
```

It is also working for more complex examples, as long as the NaN pattern is conserved among columns with NaNs:

```
In:
   a    b   c    d
0  A    H  A2   H2
1  B  NaN  B2  NaN
2  C  NaN  C2  NaN
3  D    I  D2   I2
4  E  NaN  E2  NaN
5  F  NaN  F2  NaN
6  G    J  G2   J2

Out:
   a   b   c   d
0  A   H  A2  H2
1  B  B2   C  C2
2  D   I  D2  I2
3  E  E2   F  F2
4  G   J  G2  J2
```

```
In:
   a    b    c
0  A    F    H
1  B  NaN  NaN
2  C  NaN  NaN
3  D  NaN  NaN
4  E    G    I

Out:
   a  b  c
0  A  F  H
1  B  C  D
2  E  G  I
```

In case NaNs columns do not have the same pattern such as:

```
   a    b   c    d
0  A    H  A2  NaN
1  B  NaN  B2  NaN
2  C  NaN  C2   H2
3  D    I  D2   I2
4  E  NaN  E2  NaN
5  F  NaN  F2  NaN
6  G    J  G2   J2
```

You can apply the operation per group of two columns:

```
def elementwise_shift(df):
    array = df.to_numpy().flatten()
    return pd.DataFrame(array[~pd.isna(array)].reshape(-1,df.shape[1]), columns=df.columns)

(df.groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[1]/2), 2), axis=1)
   .apply(elementwise_shift)
)
```

output:

```
   a  b   c   d
0  A  H  A2  B2
1  B  C  C2  H2
2  D  I  D2  I2
3  E  F  E2  F2
4  G  J  G2  J2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps with a placeholder column. First you fill all the nans in column `b` with the `a` values from the next row. Then you apply the filtering. In this example I use `ffill` with a limit of 1 to filter all nan values after the first, there's probably a better method.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,3,4],"b":[1,2,np.nan,np.nan,4]})

# Fill all nans:
df['new_b'] = df['b'].fillna(df['a'].shift(-1))
df = df[df['b'].ffill(limit=1).notna()].copy() # .copy() because loc makes a view
df = df.drop('b', axis=1).rename(columns={'new_b': 'b'})

print(df)
# output:
#    a  b
# 0  1  1
# 1  2  2
# 2  3  2
# 4  4  4
```

Comment: I will try this too and inform you, but I find @mozway answer easy. You may look there as well. I will inform you if it is working or not shortly.

Comment: Actually your answer is not working for me, just because my column data type is `int64`.

Comment: @Xitiz You can just cast that, I've update the answer

Comment: I can write `df['new_b'] = df.b.fillna(df.a.shift(-1))` this line as well. My real date's data type is `int64` then I have to write `df['new_b'] = df.1.fillna(df.0.shift(-1))` which is not possible but I tried this `df['new_b'] = df.[1].fillna(df.[0].shift(-1))` also. And it is working fine. Remove that edited line, it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: With that edited line it is giving me error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'TECHNO ASIA HOLDINGS BERHAD'` but if it works for dummy data, you may not need to change it.

Comment: @Swier: this is not working as expected. Please see the example dataframe in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68479428/16343464) as the one of OP was ambiguous. You can fix it with: `df['new_b'] = df.b.fillna(df.a.shift(-1)) ; df =
df[df.b.ffill(limit=1).notna()].drop('b', axis=1).rename(columns={'new_b': 'b'})`